# What's the difference between the topology defined by a seminorm and the topology defined by the norm it induces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

I was just wondering whether there's some big difference between the topology generated by a seminorm and the norm it induces. For instance, Suppose $X$ is normed and $A$ is a subspace. $X/A$ is semi-normed, while if $A$ is closed, $X/A$ is normed. Do the quotients have very different topologies?

Comment: @user1952009 sure, but I'd also like to know what's going on abstractly!

Comment: yes but a relevant example will help, at least me

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is, but in both cases, the seminorm is given by $||\overline{x}-\overline{y}||_{X/A}=\sup_{x', y': \overline{x'}=\overline{x}, \overline{y'}=\overline{y}} ||x-y||$. It is just that this happens to be a norm if $A$ is closed. The topologies induced by a seminorm and by a norm have the same prescription, so treating a norm as a seminorm makes no difference. It is, however, generally not equivalent to the quotient norm (unless $A$ is compact).

Comment: @Mar could you elaborate more on 'not equivalent to the quotient norm'? This is exactly what I'd like to know - the differences in topologies between the norm on $X/A$ (if $A$ is closed) and the seminorms (genera $A$).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the quotient topology, treating $X$ as a topological space, forgetting about the norm. I unfortunately cannot recall a counterexample.

Comment: @linalg: In what kind of statements are you interested? The topology generated by a norm is Hausdorff whereas the topology generated by a seminorm (which is not a norm) is not.